# Large format printer that will print on 1/8th inch material?

Tags: print-production

My company provides custom orthopedic products. Our major seller is custom foot orthotic (CFO) inserts.

The 'top cover' on the CFO, the part that touches your foot/sock is either a 1/8th in. material or a 1/16 in. material. We would like to print logos on this material. We work with different doctors offices, so I need to be able to print many different logos but in small quantities each.

I had taken the material to a local printer. They used a Roland-brand printer to print on the the smaller 1/16th in. material . They told me the printer wouldn't support the thicker 1/8th. I was hoping to find a machine that could do this work as the final results were impressive.

I've tried two alternatives. One, heat transfers. We found out that while they apply great, they come over time. Second, I tried pad printing. But we're a very small outfit. The mess, having to change the plates, the fumes from the ink/solvents, the risk of misprinting, etc. just makes this a very undesirable option for me.

In terms of the printer itself, I am looking for something under $8000 USD. I don't need many additional functions or even a high resolution. So 'cutting' would not be needed.

Comment: Have you considered to contact local silk screen operations? Someone who does small lot shirt work may be a suitable solution.